# Next.js installation error cannot find module fs/promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I'm facing issue while installing new Next.js 14 app. I browse Google as well as **Stack Overflow** but couldn't find solution.

I'm stuck here. Can anyone help me out?

**What I tried:**

`npx create-next-app@latest`

and **What get in response:**

> *npx: installed 1 in 1.775s
>
> Cannot find module 'fs/promises'*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Let's try a few things:**

I'm unsure of your Node.js version, but the fs/promises module was introduced after Node.js version 14.

run `node -v` in your terminal to check your version first.

**If you're under version 14, you'll need an upgrade.**

install nvm and run `nvm install 14`, then run `node -v` again to confirm the upgrade or, just go to https://node.js.org/en/download/

try to run the command you tried afterward.

**And then some things that may help are listed below, if that doesn't fix the issue.**

1. *Run `npm cache clean --force`. Sometimes, cached packages can and will cause issues with module resolution.*
2. *Delete and reinstall  node_modules and package-lock.json.*

   rm -rf node_modules

   rm package-lock.json

*Then reinstall.*

```
npm install
```